# React Router doesn't render Route components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an array of objects that I want to use for rendering a few templated pages. I try to map through the array and return a Route for each object:

```
  const Component = () => (
  <div className={`${styles["body"]}`}>
    {heroesArray.map((hero, i) => {
      let randomQuote = getRandomQuote(hero.quotes);
      let path = hero.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .join("_");
      return (
        <div className="thumbnail">
          <Thumbnail
            key={i}
            hero={hero}
            randomQuote={randomQuote}
            path={path}
          />
          <Route <!-- HERE I CREATE A ROUTE -->
            path={path}
            component={() => <HeroPage hero={hero} />}
            key={i + 365}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Thumbnail is wrapped in a Link tag that leads to a path that is passed down as a prop. Nothing gets rendered when I try to click on one of the thumbnails.

Full code and working app here: https://repl.it/repls/NoteworthyDetailedForm

[1](https://repl.it/repls/NoteworthyDetailedForm)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added some fixes to your repl.it, let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I got it working here:
https://repl.it/@wichopy/NoteworthyDetailedForm

Theres a few things I did.

paths should start with a forward slash ('/').
I defined all your routes inside the Main component an put it in a Switch which will only render a single route at a time.

Original: 
Your component prop inside of Route should just be the uninstantiated component, React router will handle rendering it and passing props to it.

If you want to control what props to press, use render instead of component:

```
 <Route <!-- HERE I CREATE A ROUTE -->
    path={path}
    render={(props) => <HeroPage hero={hero} {...props}/>}
    key={i + 365}
 />
```

If you intend to just use a component:

```
 <Route <!-- HERE I CREATE A ROUTE -->
    path={path}
    component={HeroPage}
    key={i + 365}
 />
```

Comment: I figured out the same thing at the same time myself and it worked, but thanks anyway) I thought that there may be some way not to map through the array twice, as this could hurt performance. Of course, my app is small and performance is not an issue, but if it was a little more complicated it would be. Probably, the problem about the first version of my code is that Routes are under the main "/" route, but I still have absolutely no idea how to fix that, so I'll probably stick to your option

Comment: After looking at this again I realized you could just use <Route path="/:heroName" /> and inside of the Main component you can decide which hero page to render by using the this.props.match.heroName value